# Android java: How to create POJO and convert it into acceptable JSON for Cloud Firestore REST API

Tags: java, android, json, rest, retrofit2

I made preview test REST API query via `postman` like this

`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/USER_ID_HASH/documents/112233445566`

JSON body example:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "longitude": {
      "doubleValue": 35.5635
    },
    "latitude": {
      "doubleValue": 45.5366
    }
  }
}
```

And getting http response `200`, so going to implement this in code using `retrofit2`.

The issue is that `"doubleValue"` is something like field transformation according to value type, so it may be also `"stringValue" or "integerValue"` for example. And question is how to create `POJO` class for further converting in `JSON` body like JSON body example above?

What do I have for now:

API

public interface PlaceholderApi {

```
@POST("{userId}/documents/{timestamp}")
Call<Transaction.Result> saveLocationToCloud(
    @Path("userId") String userId,
    @Path("timestamp") long timestamp,
    @Body LocationData data
);
```

}

Network service

```
public class NetworkService {

private static NetworkService instance;

private static final String WEB_API_KEY = "zaSy..........VWI";

private static final String BASE_URL_CLOUD
    = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/alocationtracker/databases/(default)/documents/";

private Retrofit retrofit;

private NetworkService() {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor);

    client.interceptors().add(chain -> {
        Request request = chain.request();
        HttpUrl url = request.url().newBuilder().addQueryParameter("key", WEB_API_KEY).build();
        request = request.newBuilder().url(url).build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL_CLOUD)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client.build())
        .build();
}

public static NetworkService getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new NetworkService();
    }
    return instance;
}

public PlaceholderApi getJsonApi() {
    return retrofit.create(PlaceholderApi.class);
}
```

}

POJO

```
public class LocationData {
    @SerializedName("userId")
    @Expose
    private String userId;

    @SerializedName("timestamp")
    @Expose
    private long timestamp;

    @SerializedName("longitude")
    @Expose
    private double longitude;

    @SerializedName("latitude")
    @Expose
    private double latitude;

    public LocationData(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public LocationData(String userId, Location location) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.timestamp = location.getTime();
        this.latitude = location.getLatitude();
        this.longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}
```

JSON I got with this has incorrect format without value type like `"doubleValue"` etc.

```
{"latitude":19.9802209,"longitude":16.1852646,"timestamp":1599830853181,"userId":"2DBtYfX1uxQszxNmod83"}
```

I assume POJO class is the only thing I need to change somehow. Or maybe I need to change `retrofit.create(PlaceholderApi.class)` on something else?

Any suggestions, please.

Thanks.

Comment: LocationData this class is for request right, can you post your model for reponse. Transaction.Result i guess here you can change and you will get the results.

Comment: @vikaskumar I don't have response model yet. What for response model needed in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting below response from the API

```
    {
  "fields": {
    "longitude": {
      "doubleValue": 35.5635
    },
    "latitude": {
      "doubleValue": 45.5366
    }
  }
}
```

then change your model to something like below.

```
public class PlacesResponseModel {

@SerializedName("fields")
@Expose
private Fields fields;

public Fields getFields() {
return fields;
}

public void setFields(Fields fields) {
this.fields = fields;
}

}

public class Fields {

@SerializedName("longitude")
@Expose
private Longitude longitude;
@SerializedName("latitude")
@Expose
private Latitude latitude;

public Longitude getLongitude() {
return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Longitude longitude) {
this.longitude = longitude;
}

public Latitude getLatitude() {
return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Latitude latitude) {
this.latitude = latitude;
}

}


public class Latitude {

@SerializedName("doubleValue")
@Expose
private Double doubleValue;

public Double getDoubleValue() {
return doubleValue;
}

public void setDoubleValue(Double doubleValue) {
this.doubleValue = doubleValue;
}

}
public class Longitude {

@SerializedName("doubleValue")
@Expose
private Double doubleValue;

public Double getDoubleValue() {
return doubleValue;
}

public void setDoubleValue(Double doubleValue) {
this.doubleValue = doubleValue;
}

}
```

and add it in the retrofit API callback like below.

```
public interface PlaceholderApi {

@POST("{userId}/documents/{timestamp}")
Call<PlacesResponseModel> saveLocationToCloud(
    @Path("userId") String userId,
    @Path("timestamp") long timestamp,
    @Body LocationData data
);
}
```

last step call this now, you should get your models mapped